# Automapper Parent Child Mapping sets Grandchildren Properties as null

Tags: recursion, orm, automapper, poco, dto

Automapper seems to be ignoring grandchild objects when mapping between objects. So that i only get 2 levels of recursion. I need at least 3, ideally n levels.

**How do I get Automapper to return the correct object with all children intact?**

I can work around it, by serializing my DbPOCO and deserializing to the Dto, but that means crossing concerns in my application, and/or doing something different for this specific method which I don't like.

Given my DB Poco

```
    public class Menu : SqlTable, IParentChild<Menu>
    {
       public string Label {get; set;}
       public string Route {get; set;}
       public float Sequence { get; set; }
       public int? ParentID {get; set;}
       public Menu Parent {get; set;}
       public IList<Menu> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

I can return (with some recursive magic) an object which serializes like this, but it includes (removed) database audit columns and other table generic items that I don't want communicated over my API.

```
[
  {
    "Label": "Main Menu 1",
    "Route": "",
    "Sequence": 1,
    "ParentID": null,
    "Parent": null,
    "Children": [
      {
        "Label": "Menu 1 Sub 1",
        "Route": "",
        "Sequence": 1,
        "ParentID": 1,
        "Parent": null,
        "Children": [
          {
            "Label": "Menu 1 Sub 1 Sub 1",
            "Route": "",
            "Sequence": 1,
            "ParentID": 2,
            "Parent": null,
            "Children": [],
            ...
          },
          {
            "Label": "Menu 1 Sub 1 Sub 2",
            "Route": "",
            "Sequence": 2,
            "ParentID": 2,
            "Parent": null,
            "Children": [],
            ...
          }
        ],
        ...
      },
      {
        "Label": "Menu 1 Sub 2",
        "Route": "",
        "Sequence": 2,
        "ParentID": 1,
        "Parent": null,
        "Children": [],
        "ID": 5,
        ...
      }
    ],
    ...
  },
  {
    "Label": "Main Menu 2",
    "Route": "",
    "Sequence": 2,
    "ParentID": null,
    "Parent": null,
    "Children": [
      {
        "Label": "Menu 2 Sub 1",
        "Route": "",
        "Sequence": 1,
        "ParentID": 6,
        "Parent": null,
        "Children": [],
        ...
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
]
```

When i pass this into Automapper, to map it to the following DTO

```
public class WebApplicationMenuModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Route { get; set; }
        public float Sequence { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<WebApplicationMenuModel> Children { get; set; }

    }
```

The grandchildren from my original object are set to null

```
[
  {
    "Label": "Main Menu 1",
    "Route": "",
    "Sequence": 1,
    "Children": [
      {
        "Label": "Menu 1 Sub 1",
        "Route": "",
        "Sequence": 1,
        "Children": null
      },
      {
        "Label": "Menu 1 Sub 2",
        "Route": "",
        "Sequence": 2,
        "Children": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Label": "Main Menu 2",
    "Route": "",
    "Sequence": 2,
    "Children": [
      {
        "Label": "Menu 2 Sub 1",
        "Route": "",
        "Sequence": 1,
        "Children": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The map profile is fairly basic

```
    public class MenuProfile : Profile
    {
        public MenuProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Menu, WebApplicationMenuModel>()
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not possible in EF6.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm using EFCore 3. However, by the time that this object hits Automapper, it has been worked on by the underlying service, so I'm not passing in the Enumerable from EF, i'm building a totally new list using a recursive Extension Method.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3349

Comment: That has fixed it! Christ! Committed 6 days ago. That's excellent. Hadn't even thought to check their Git Development list. Lesson Learned.

Answer (score 1):

See Reply by Lucian Bargaoanu. Needed to user the master Automapper branch (9.1.0-ci-01627) to support this from MyGet.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/The-MyGet-build.html